# Ruby unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a nested for loop

```
    size = 50
    for j in 1..size
        for k j..attempts
        **DO SOMETHING**
        end
    end
```

However, I am getting this error

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
                for k j..attempts
                      ^
game.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: `for` loops are incredibly rare in Ruby, you'd usually say `(1..size).each do |j| ... end` instead.

Comment: Alternatively there's `1.upto(size) do |j| ... end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line of your code.

```
for k j..attempts
```

Change it into

```
for k in j..attempts
```

Your final solution will be.

```
size = 50
for j in 1..size
    for k in j..attempts
    **DO SOMETHING**
    end
end
```